# How to calculate using postgres the customer rebooking rate

Tags: postgresql

I need to calculate the re-bookings rate percentage by teacher for a given time range, my table structure is fairly standard for an e-commerce platform, tables include `booking`, `customer` and `teacher`, included below:

> Re-bookings rate: a customer can create a booking for any teacher but each booking can only have one teacher at a time.  The re-bookings rate is when a teacher is booked more than once by the same customer.  The teacher with the highest percentage means the teacher has more repeat bookings than any other teacher.

I wondered whether a temporary table needs to be created for each teacher with a list bookings?

**table: Booking**

```
id, customer_id, teacher_id
```

**table: Customer**

```
id, email, forename, surname
```

**table: Teacher**

```
id, name, email
```

I have the following query but I'm not sure how to calculate the re-bookings rate!?

```
SELECT t.id, t.email
FROM booking b
JOIN customer c on c.id = b.customer_id
JOIN teacher t on t.id = b.teacher_id
WHERE b.time_created = "..."
```

**Sample dataset**

Booking

```
id, customer_id, teacher_id
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
3, 6, 2
4, 8, 4
5, 4, 3
6, 1, 1
```

Customer

```
id, email, forename, surname
1, tom@test.com, tom, smith
2, rachel@test.com, rachel, green
3, jeff@lycos.com, jeff, price
4, max@google.com, max, cooper
5, tom@msn.com, tom, white
6, pete@gmail.com, pete, tinner
7, lenny@hotmail.com, lenny, allen
8, noel@gmail.com, noel, ashton
```

Teacher

```
id, name, email
1, john, john@schoolexample1.edu 
2, gavin, gavin@schoolexample1.edu
3, gordon, gordon@schoolexample1.edu
4, hazel, hazel@schoolexample1.edu
```

**Desired data output**

[image: data ouput]

**Latest query version update**

[image: screenshot data output]

Comment: Please define what you call *rebooking rate*. Sample data and desired results would make your question clearer.

Comment: I've added a definition of rebooking rate

Comment: Not clear to me whether you are looking for re-booking rate for a given customer over many teachers or for a teacher that has the most re-bookings over all customers? As @GMB stated an example of the output you expect would be helpful.

Comment: I'll add an example -> this is what I'm seeking for "..or for a teacher that has the most re-bookings over all customers"

Comment: working on getting an example dataset now

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ifrew7x2u59UCb3nKstVsf/1

Comment: Any thoughts on this? @AdrianKlaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts on this:

```
SELECT 
    t_ct.teacher_id, teacher.forename, t_ct.customer_id, customer.forename, ct,
    SUM(ct) OVER(PARTITION BY t_ct.teacher_id)
FROM  
    (SELECT 
        teacher_id, customer_id, count(*) AS ct 
     FROM 
        booking 
     JOIN 
        teacher 
     ON 
        booking.teacher_id = teacher.id 
     GROUP BY 
        teacher_id, customer_id) AS t_ct  
JOIN 
    teacher 
ON 
    t_ct.teacher_id = teacher.id  
JOIN 
    customer 
ON 
    t_ct.customer_id = customer.id 
ORDER BY 
    teacher.forename, ct desc;

teacher_id | forename | customer_id | forename | ct | sum 
------------+----------+-------------+----------+----+-----
          4 | jennifer |           1 | oliver   |  1 |   1
          3 | max      |           1 | oliver   |  1 |   2
          3 | max      |           2 | chandler |  1 |   2
          2 | terry    |           2 | chandler |  3 |   5
          2 | terry    |           3 | sarah    |  1 |   5
          2 | terry    |           4 | vicky    |  1 |   5

Changing the ORDER BY:

sum desc, ct desc, teacher.forename;

would get a better picture:

 teacher_id | forename | customer_id | forename | ct | sum 
------------+----------+-------------+----------+----+-----
          2 | terry    |           2 | chandler |  3 |   5
          2 | terry    |           3 | sarah    |  1 |   5
          2 | terry    |           4 | vicky    |  1 |   5
          3 | max      |           1 | oliver   |  1 |   2
          3 | max      |           2 | chandler |  1 |   2
          4 | jennifer |           1 | oliver   |  1 |   1
```

The `SUM(ct) OVER(PARTITION BY t_ct.teacher_id)` portion is a [Window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) that calculates the sum of bookings a teacher has, per 'total_number_of_bookings' request from the dbfiddle. Basically it sums the bookings per `teacher_id`. It repeats for each row for a given `teacher_id`.

UPDATE 12/10/2020. Using [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#id-1.11.7.47.4) module to do a crosstab on a temporary table. Not complete as it does not deal  with 4+ bookings.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE booking_rate AS
SELECT 
    t_ct.teacher_id, teacher.forename, ct, 
    SUM(ct)  OVER(PARTITION BY t_ct.teacher_id) AS total
FROM  
    (select teacher_id, ct, count(*) from (SELECT
        teacher_id, customer_id, count(*) AS ct
     FROM
        booking
     JOIN
        teacher
     ON
        booking.teacher_id = teacher.id
     GROUP BY
        teacher_id, customer_id) as t_c_ct group by teacher_id, ct) AS t_ct
JOIN 
    teacher 
ON 
    t_ct.teacher_id = teacher.id  
ORDER BY 
    teacher.forename, ct desc;

select * from booking_rate ;
 
teacher_id | forename | ct | total 
------------+----------+----+-------
          4 | jennifer |  1 |     1
          3 | max      |  1 |     1
          2 | terry    |  3 |     4
          2 | terry    |  1 |     4

SELECT t_id, name, total, round(coalesce(ct/total::numeric, 0), 2) * 100 AS one, 
    round(coalesce(ct2/total::numeric, 0), 2) * 100 AS two, round(coalesce(ct3/total::numeric, 0) ,2) * 100 as three, 
    round(coalesce(ct4/total::numeric, 0), 2) * 100 AS four
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM  crosstab (
    'SELECT teacher_id, forename, total, ct, ct FROM booking_rate ORDER BY 1',
    'SELECT booking from generate_series(1,4) AS booking'
) AS (
    t_id int, 
    name varchar,
    total int,
    ct int,
    ct2 int,
    ct3 int,
    ct4 int
) 
    )AS c_tab
;
 t_id |   name   | total |  one   | two  | three | four 
------+----------+-------+--------+------+-------+------
    2 | terry    |     4 |  25.00 | 0.00 | 75.00 | 0.00
    3 | max      |     1 | 100.00 | 0.00 |  0.00 | 0.00
    4 | jennifer |     1 | 100.00 | 0.00 |  0.00 | 0.00
(3 rows)
```

Comment: thanks for this!  Not sure what the over partition is doing??

Comment: this looks like it's the right direction but it doesn't provide the "rebooking rate"

Comment: the "rebooking rate" needs to be a percentage of customer's that have booked only once for a given teacher, only 2 times, only 3 times and more than 3 times

Comment: That definition of rebooking rate does match that in your question. Please provide an example of the output you want using the data you provided. Include that in the question.

Comment: I've updated the question, first row means teacher "Max" has 320 bookings and 25% of those bookings (25% of 320 = 80 customers) have only booked "Max" once and not again.

Comment: let me know if you need more information - thanks

Comment: Don't need more information, just some time to get to this.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a screen shot.  Shows multiple lines for each teacher?

Comment: A screenshot of what? You have the basics of what can be done you will need to adapt to whatever your data actually is.

Comment: ok, let me look at the query and the results and try to understand the query to at least some extent.  Will come back to you asap!